# C# UDP Server Asynchronous Multiple Clients | SocketException When Client Disconnect

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I've been working on a socket server program in C# (I was inspired from this [post](http://acrocontext.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/c-simple-udp-listener-in-asynchronous-way/)) and my problem is that when a client disconnects an exception "**An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**" appears when the call **EndReceiveFrom()** and returns **0**, the **ref clientEP** becomes the client normally close. I don't understand why my **DoReceiveFrom()** function is called if there is nothing to read. I probably missed something. What is wrong ?

Problem appear there :

```
int dataLen = this.serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
```

The full source code:

```
class UDPServer
{
    private Socket serverSocket = null;
    private List<EndPoint> clientList = new List<EndPoint>();
    private List<Tuple<EndPoint, byte[]>> dataList = new List<Tuple<EndPoint, byte[]>>();
    private byte[] byteData = new byte[1024];
    private int port = 4242;

    public List<Tuple<EndPoint, byte[]>> DataList
    {
        private set { this.dataList = value; }
        get { return (this.dataList); }
    }

    public UDPServer(int port)
    {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        this.serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        this.serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.port));
        EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        this.serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.byteData, 0, this.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, newClientEP);
    }

    private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        try
        {
            EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            int dataLen = this.serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
            byte[] data = new byte[dataLen];
            Array.Copy(this.byteData, data, dataLen);

            if (!this.clientList.Any(client => client.Equals(clientEP)))
                this.clientList.Add(clientEP);

            EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            this.serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.byteData, 0, this.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, newClientEP);

            DataList.Add(Tuple.Create(clientEP, data));
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        }
    }

    public void SendTo(byte[] data, EndPoint clientEP)
    {
        try
        {
            this.serverSocket.SendTo(data, clientEP);
        }
        catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException)
        {
            this.clientList.Remove(clientEP);
        }
    }

    public void SendToAll(byte[] data)
    {
        foreach (var client in this.clientList)
        {
            this.SendTo(data, client);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.serverSocket.Close();
        this.serverSocket = null;

        this.dataList.Clear();
        this.clientList.Clear();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

---

**Update:**
I tried to run my client (netcat) on another pc and the exception no longer appears, even when **SendTo()**, which is also problematic to delete my client in my **clientList**.
I still do not understand what is happening.

Comment: having the same problem, were you ever able to fix it?

Comment: I think that, when closing, calling the `DoReceiveFrom` is a way to get back in user code, the errorcode (disconnected) is (probably) stored and when the `EndReceiveFrom` is called, it will check the errorcode, if the error code <> 0 then it will throw the exception. (but.. like I said, just speculation) I'd rathen don't get exceptions, disconnection shouldn't be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is as it should be.

This is the way *all* Async methods work: you invoke **BeginDo()** and pass into it your implementation of  **AsyncCallback** delegate (in your example that's **DoReceiveFrom**). You implementation starts executing immediately after that - **BeginDo()** is not a blocking call.

Inside your implementation, you must call **EndDo()**, which will **block** until one of two things happen: the object, on which you invoked **BeginDo()**, actually *does* something, or it throws an exception doing it. As it does in your case when client disconnects.

The [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on the Async method.

What you need to do for the whole thing to work is

1. Make sure that you handle that client-disconnected exception properly
2. Make sure that you call **BeginReceiveFrom** regardless of the way **EndReceiveFrom** finishes. And preferably, call **BeginReceiveFrom** immediately after you call **EndReceiveFrom**. This is needed because while you server is in-between those calls, it does not actually listen to the socket.

I would put another try-catch around EndReceiveFrom.

**UPDATE**:

```
private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    try
    {
        EndPoint clientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        int dataLen = 0;
        byte[] data = null;
        try
        {
            dataLen = this.serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref clientEP);
            data = new byte[dataLen];
            Array.Copy(this.byteData, data, dataLen);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            EndPoint newClientEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            this.serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(this.byteData, 0, this.byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref newClientEP, DoReceiveFrom, newClientEP);
        }

        if (!this.clientList.Any(client => client.Equals(clientEP)))
            this.clientList.Add(clientEP);

        DataList.Add(Tuple.Create(clientEP, data));
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem remains the same.

Comment: @user3626081, ok, but do you at least understand why **DoReceiveFrom()** function is called if there is nothing to read? Also, I updated my answer with code sample - see if that helps you